# How to make gotoxy() function select the node in the link list the cursor is on?

Tags: c++, winapi, linked-list, text-editor

I am writing a basic text editor as an assignment and I am having trouble. I am using linked lists and I can move the cursor around the list but every time I try to insert a letter (one letter a node) in between others it just inserts the letter at the end of the list. The code has other errors in general only looking for help on this main question but any suggestions is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Node

{
public:

    char c;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};



void gotoxy(int x, int y)

{
    COORD pos = { x, y };
    HANDLE output = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(output, pos);
}


void createNew()

{

    Node* start = nullptr;
    Node* end = nullptr;
    Node* prevNode = nullptr;
    int xcur = 0, ycur = 0;
    char letter = ' ';

    while (letter != 27)
    {
        letter = _getch();
        if (letter == 8) // backspace
        {
            Node *p;
            p = end;
            end = end->prev;
            delete p;
            end->next = nullptr;
            xcur--;

        }

        else if (letter == 57) //save press '9'
        {
            ofstream outdoc;
            outdoc.open("TheEditor.txt");
            Node* save;
            char data;
            save = start;
            while (save->next != nullptr)
            {
                data = save->c;
                outdoc << data;
                save = save->next;
            }
            outdoc.close();

        }

        else if (letter == -32)
        {
            // he pressed right up left or down
            letter = _getch();

            if (letter == 75) //72 is up 75 left 77 right 80 down
                --xcur;

            if (letter == 77)
                xcur++;

            //if (letter == 72)
                //ycur++;
            //if (letter == 80)
                //ycur--;


        }

        else if (letter == 56) //load file
        {
            ifstream indoc;
            string fname;
            cout << "Please enter the name of the file" << endl;
            cin >> fname;
            indoc.open(fname);
            char file[sizeof(indoc)];
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(fname); j++)

            {
                indoc >> file[j];
                cout << file[j];
                j++;
            }

        }

        else if (letter == 13) // enter

        {

            xcur = 1;
            ycur++;
            //start = arr[ycur];

        }



        else // normal eltter

        {

            Node* p;
            p = new Node();
            p->c = letter;
            p->next = nullptr;
            p->prev = nullptr;
            if (start == nullptr)
            {
                start = p;
                end = p;
                prevNode = p;
            }

            else if (end->next != nullptr) // insert in middle
            {
                Node* m = new Node();
                m->next = end;
                m->c = letter;
                m->prev = prevNode;
                end->prev = m;
                prevNode = m;


            }

            else

            {
                p->prev = prevNode;
                end->next = p;
                end = p;
                prevNode = p;
            }

            //xcur++;

        }

        system("cls");
        // display your linked list here.
        Node *p;
        p = start;
        while (p != nullptr)
        {
            _putch(p->c);
            p = p->next;
        }
        gotoxy(xcur, ycur);

    }

}



void loadFile()
{
    string fname;
    ifstream indoc;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the document" << endl;
    cin >> fname;
    system("CLS");
    indoc.open(fname);
    Node* start = nullptr;
    Node* end = nullptr;
    Node* prevNode = nullptr;
    int xcur = 0, ycur = 0;
    char letter = ' ';
    char file[sizeof(indoc)];
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(fname); j++)

    {
        indoc >> file[j];
        cout << file[j];
        j++;
    }

    indoc.close();

    while (letter != 27)

    {

        _putch(letter);
        if (start == nullptr)

        {
            Node* p;
            p = new Node();
            p->c = letter;
            p->next = nullptr;
            p->prev = nullptr;
            start = p;
            end = p;
            prevNode = p;
        }

        else

        {
            Node* t;
            t = new Node();
            t->c = letter;
            t->next = nullptr;
            t->prev = prevNode;
            end->next = t;
            end = t;
            prevNode = t;
        }

        letter = _getch();


        if (letter == 57) //save press '9'
        {
            ofstream outdoc;
            outdoc.open("RereTheEditor.txt");
            Node* save;
            char data;
            save = start;
            while (save->next != nullptr)
            {
                data = save->c;
                outdoc << data;
                save = save->next;
            }

            outdoc.close();

        }

    }
}



int main()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "Welcome to theEditor 2.0!\n"
        << "Please select an option\n"
        << "1. Create New\n"
        << "2. Load File" << endl;

    cin >> choice;
    system("CLS");
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1: { createNew(); }
            break;
    case 2: { loadFile(); }
            break;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: For clarity I would suggest using character literals rater than decimal integers. ie '9' rather than 57. It makes your code much easier to follow.

Comment: A linked list of characters would not be my first choice for this, even a linked list of strings would be better. Either way, you should have a separate class for your linked list. This would make linked list operations consistent and easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I have to do it this way that was the assignment. Does anybody know an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You must record the corresponding cursor coordinates in each node before you can pass through it.

```
class Node
{
public:
    char c;
    COORD pos;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    void setpos(int x, int y)
    {
        pos.X = x;
        pos.Y = y;
    }
};
```

Get the current cursor coordinates`bInfo.dwCursorPosition` with [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo):

```
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bInfo;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hOut, &bInfo);
```

then go to the link list to find the corresponding node of the same position, then insert, and update the coordinates of each node.